# Computational Complexity of Finding Area Under Discrete Curve

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, calculus

I apologize if my questions are extremely misguided or loosely scoped. Math is not my strongest subject. For context, I am trying to figure out the computational complexity of calculating the area under a discrete curve. In the particular use case that I am interested in, the y-axis is the length of a queue and the x-axis is time. The curve will always have the following bounds: it begins at zero, it is composed of multiple timestamped samples that are greater than zero, and it eventually shrinks to zero. My initial research has yielded two potential mathematical approaches to this problem. The first is a Reimann sum over domain [a, b] where a is initially zero and b eventually becomes zero (not sure if my understanding is completely correct there). I think the mathematical representation of this the formula found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration.

The second is a discrete convolution. However, I am unable to tell the difference between, and applicability of, a discrete convolution and a Reimann sum over domain [a, b] where a is initially zero and b eventually becomes zero.

My questions are:

- Is there are difference between the two?
- Which approach is most applicable/efficient for what I am trying to figure out?
- Is it even appropriate ask the computation complexity of either mathematical approach? If so, what are the complexities of each in this particular application?

Edit:
For added context, there will be a function calculating average queue length by taking the sum of the area under two separate curves and dividing it by the total time interval spanning those two curves. The particular application can be seen on page 168 of this paper: https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cv/raj_jain_paper4_decbit.pdf

Comment: If you were to use a discrete convolution to solve this problem, what would the two input functions be?

Comment: Wouldn't this go better on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'm not sure how to answer that question, which is probably an indication of a larger misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @harold I will try to post it over there and see what I get.

Comment: For someone who doesn't know a lot of math, it looks like you're trying to apply a lot of math to a fundamentally simple problem.  Why is the answer not "just add up all the length samples and multiply by the timestamp interval"?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I suppose there is more context required. There will be a function calculating average queue length by taking the sum of the area under two separate curves and dividing it by the total time interval spanning those two curves. The particular application can be seen on page 168 of this paper: https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cv/raj_jain_paper4_decbit.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> Is there are difference between the two?

A [discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) requires two functions. If the first one corresponds to the discrete curve, what is the second one?

> Which approach is most applicable/efficient for what I am trying to figure out?

A [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) is an approximation of an *integral*. It's typically used to approximate the area under a continuous curve. You can of course use it on a discrete curve, but it's not an approximation anymore, and I'm not sure you can call it a "Riemann" sum.

> Is it even appropriate ask the computation complexity of either mathematical approach? If so, what are the complexities of each in this particular application?

In any case, the complexity of computing the area under a dicrete curve is linear in the number of samples, and it's pretty straightforward to find why: you need to do something with each sample, once or twice.

---

What you probably want looks like a Riemann sum with the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Trapezoidal_rule). Pick the first two samples, calculate their average, and multiply that by the distance between two samples. Repeat for every adjacent pair and sum it all.

Comment: I suppose the two input functions would be two discrete curves (see page 168 here for context https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cv/raj_jain_paper4_decbit.pdf). It's very possible that I am misunderstanding convolutions. Thank you for the input. I will look into the trapezoidal rule!

Answer (score 2):

So, this is for the router feedback filter in the referenced paper...

That algorithm is specifically designed so that you can implement it without storing a lot of samples and timestamps.

It works by accumulating total **queue_length * time** during each cycle.

- At the start of each "cycle", record the current queue length and current clock time and set the current cycle's total to 0.  (The paper defines the cycle so that the queue length is 0 at the start, but that's not important here)
- every time the queue length changes, get the new current clock time and add **(new_clock_time - previous_clock_time) * previous_queue_length** to the total.  Also do this at the end of the cycle.  *Then*, record new new current queue length and current clock time.
- When you need to calculate the current "average queue length", it's just **(previous_cycle_total + current_cycle_total + (current_clock_time - previous_clock_time)*previous_queue_length) / total_time_since_previous_cycle_start**